# Carrinho de compras com valor inferior a 1

Tags: php

Olá !
Tenho um carrinho que de compras com 2 imagens, uma para aumentar e outra para diminuir a quantidade. Tudo funciona bem (aumenta a quantidade e atualiza o subtotal e tb o total. O mesmo acontece quando diminuo.) Tenho um botão para remover cada item, que tb funciona perfeitamente. O problema é que a quantidade não pode ser menor que 1, pois ele vai decrementando (0, -1, -2....) e vai atualizando os valores com valor negativo. 
Enfim, preciso que a quantidade não seja menor que 1 ou, se for, que o item seja removido.
Agradeço desde já quem puder me ajudar.

Segue o código:

```
<?php

    require ("conexao.php");

    if(count($_SESSION['valida_carrinho']) == 0){

       echo "
             <table style='background-color:#EEEEEE; width:94%; height:40px; text-align:center; margin-top:10px; margin-left:40px; font-size:15px;'>
                 <tr>
                   <td><strong>Não há produtos no carrinho.</strong></td>                
                 </tr>
             </table>";

       }else{           

       $total = 0;

       foreach($_SESSION['valida_carrinho'] as $id => $quantidade){

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = '$id'";
         $query = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql)or die (mysqli_error());
         $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

         $imagem = $line['imagem'];
         $nome = $line['nome'];
         $preco = $line['preco'];
         $subtotal = $line['preco'] * $quantidade;
         $total = $total += $subtotal;  
         $_SESSION['total'] = $total;            

         echo'
           <table>

            <tr><td><img src ="imagens/'.$line['imagem'].'"/></td>
            <tr><td>'.$nome.'</td></tr>
            <tr><td>R$ '.number_format($preco, 2, ',', '.').'</td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><a href="?acao=sub&id='.$id.'"><img src = "imagens/negativo.png"></a>
            <input id= "product" type = "text" name = "product['.$id.']" value = "'.$quantidade.'"style="text-align:center; width:25px; height:25px;"/></a>
            <a href="?acao=add&id='.$id.'"><img src = "imagens/positivo.png"></a></td>
            </tr>                         
            <tr><td><a href="?acao=del&id='.$id.'">Remover</a></td>

           </table>';       

       }
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o código onde você efetivamente diminui o valor, na URL  `?acao=sub&id='.$id.'`

Comment: //alterar quantidade
  if($_GET['acao'] == 'up'){
    if(is_array($_POST['product'])){
      foreach($_POST['product'] as $id => $quantidade){
      $id = intval($id);
   $quantidade = intval($quantidade);
   
   if(!empty($quantidade) || $quantidade <> 0){
      $_SESSION['valida_carrinho'][$id] = $quantidade;
      
   }else{
      unset($_SESSION['valida_carrinho'][$id]);
    
     }
   }
    }
  }

Comment: Na pergunta, obviamente.

Comment: esses códigos são suficientes ?

Comment: Vc me deu um luz. Parece que o problema está na SESSION:

Comment: if($_GET['acao'] == 'sub'){
  
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['valida_carrinho'][$id])){
    
      $_SESSION['valida_carrinho'][$id] = 1;
    
    }else{
    
      $_SESSION['valida_carrinho'][$id] -= 1;
    
    }  
  
  }

Comment: Resolvi:  if($_GET['acao'] == 'sub'){
  
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    if(($_SESSION['valida_carrinho'][$id] == 1)){
    
      $_SESSION['valida_carrinho'][$id] = 1;
    
    }else{
    
      $_SESSION['valida_carrinho'][$id] -= 1;
    
    }  
  
  }